# User-Experience tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I recently saw the tags to [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15806/does-inflating-scores-make-players-happier) question, and I believe that 'experience' is an incorrect tag.

I think we need a 'user-experience' tag for this type of question as it is both game-design and user-experience related.

Comment: If you get 12 more rep you'll be able to do it yourself.  http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Went ahead and made the change.