# Should we blacklist [experience]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm guessing the [experience](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience) tag was once meant for what is now [user-experience](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-experience), based on this question [User-Experience tag](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/544/user-experience-tag).

Now the few questions that use it, are using it as meta. Typically, balancing experience, or formula for calculating experience. Which are covered by the [balance](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balance), [formula](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formula), or [algorithm](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [experience](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience) should be blacklisted. The name is not specific enough about how it should be used, and even if it were to be used for "experience points", it would be too specific and could be covered by the other tags you mentioned, or by [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design) if appropriate.

Comment: I don't have permission to set this in motion. Is there a way to formally request this other than a question like this?

Comment: @Chris Blacklisting a tag is done manually, this means that we have to go through all the questions one by one and remove the tag manually. Then we add the tag to [the list of blacklisted tags](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/which-tags-are-useless-or-blacklisted). What you lack is the ability to edit without your edits going through the review queue, but you have all the permissions :) You could start editing the tags out, and putting a link to this question in the edit description. Other users will approve them.

Comment: I shall continue to +2 my way up the chart!

Comment: @Chris There you go ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's too ambiguous a tag name, since it could be about three different things at least, and should be replaced with more specifically meaningful tags:

- user experience (covered by [user-experience](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-experience))
- experience points (could/should be covered by a tag like [experience-points](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-points) or something)
- personal experience (shouldn't have a tag)

Comment: `user-experience` is in and good. But I think that `experience points` is too specific, and `personal experience` is going to lead to opinion based questions and answers.

Comment: @Chris Oh right. I should clarify I'm by no means suggesting that "personal experience" should be a tag, it'd be rubbish. Just that [experience] doesn't suggest it's *not* about that thing.